# I can't seem to get superscript to show up, like I squared should be I^2

Tags: support

In my answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/53212/9730) I have tried to get P = I^2 * R to show the 2 in super script, several different ways, like P = I^{2} * R as mentioned [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/438/9730).

How is it done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This site supports the LaTeX syntax and rendering through the [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) engine.

You can use the normal LaTeX syntax, but you have to enclose the formulas in `$$` tags for centered formulas, `\$` tags for inline formulas.

There is a sandbox [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/434/test-the-new-latex-markdown-in-this-sandbox-question), where you can find several examples.

Answer (score 3):

`<sub>` and `<sup>` tags would do the job too

I<sup>2</sup>R<sub>load</sub> is produced by `I<sup>2</sup>R<sub>load</sub>`

Comment: +1 I didn't know those were supported here.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of superscript-2, you can also use the native HTML "&sup2;" construct, like

P = I² R

Comment: +1 Makes sense, I didn't think about it. I'm new to things like LaTeX and am trying to learn to make my answers better, etc. One unrelated question for you, I've seen a good amount of comments from you like [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/53028/how-to-remove-enamel-from-wire), '*You "wanna"? We speak English here.*' I just wanted to ask if you were ever an English teacher or anything? I understand why you do it, and it seems like it's when an OP uses bad grammar/punctuation, etc. I was just interested to know, thanks. (I almost ended this with my *thx* shorthand.)

Comment: @Garrett: Sloppy text is annoying to read and generally devalues the whole site. Foreigners get some slack, but there is no excuse for not following a few basic rules of the language or just being lazy. For example, even those new to English can capitalize the first letter of a sentence. Stuff like "wanna" and "thx" is just being lazy at the expense of everyone else here. I don't want to let people get away with that. Letting it derail their question, downvoting, and even closing bad cases are all ways we can insist on a little respect from those that come here for free help.